# Delete Query should execute after session is automatically destroyed

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am having problem with session destroy. I am running a script called logout.php in that file I am destroying user session also I am executing a query which will delete my shopping bag. This is working properly but when I closed the browser or session is automatically destroy after sometime , that time I have to delete my shopping bag off course in this situation logout.php will not call. So how can I achieve this .

logout.php :-

```
<?php
include_once('functions/config.php');
session_start();


$sql = "DELETE FROM baskets WHERE member_id = '".$_SESSION['memid']."' ";

mysql_query($sql);

session_destroy();   


header('location:index.php')

?>
```

Comment: so, in short, you want to execute a query when browser is closed or session destroyed. Right?

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` extension anymore, it's being deprecated.The man-pages will tell you what to use instead (PDO or mysqli_*). Preferably PDO, as it supports more than just mysql, and is more in tune with the times (OO API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two answers for this questions:
1) you can clear your shopping bag using javascript event window.onbeforeunload
 example:

```
     window.onbeforeunload= function(){
        // your ajax call to clear shopping bag
     }
```

2)I will recommend this option:
  You can clear users shopping bag on his login.

Comment: Thanks @sumit souda , now I am deleting my shopping bag when user is login as well as when he click on logout link.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem but `onbeforeunload` is not reliable enough to clear a cart with limited item stock. It's not supported in Mobile Browsers (e.g. iOS Safari) or Opera.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to write code that you can safely assume that it's called when a session is destroyed.

Easiest way to do what you want is to set a "last accessed" timestamp on your basket that you update on every access, and then run a cron job (scheduled job) every hour or so that deletes all baskets that haven't been accessed in, let's say, 6 hours or more. That won't delete it at the same time as the session times out, but will keep old baskets out of the database in the long run.

Comment: that's what i'd like to do as well. Sadly the cron job thing is a bit out of my league yet. But it seems like i can't get around it.

Comment: @eggyal Where is your answer ??

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH: My answer wasn't the solution I had thought, and so I deleted it.

Comment: @eggyal Means performing DB query on session destroy is not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to clean the shopping bag when (for example) the users' browser closes? You could give a warning like 'You have not logged out correctly last time, do you want to continue shopping or start fresh?' , something like that.

HTTP is a stateless protocol, so you can't tell when a browser actually closes. In my opinion you need to work with session timeouts, so that after a period of time has passed the shopping bag gets cleared anyway unless there still is user activity.

Hope that helps.